# What is the simplest way to make a specific page the default page in an html directory?

Tags: html

My html folder contains many html files automatically generated, linked and named by a program. Example: AbcXyzPage1.html, AbcXyzPage2.html, ..., AbcXyzPage100.html, etc.

What is the simplest way to make a particular html file (AbcXyzPage1.html), the equivalent of default.html? So that a user just need to type http://mysite.com/myfolder/ and has that particular page loaded.
Renaming that starting page is NOT an option because all other pages in the folder link to it.

**I don't want to use the meta refresh tag.**

Comment: What web server will you be using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a file named `.htaccess` to `myfolder/` with the following content:

```
DirectoryIndex AbcXyzPage1.html
```

Answer (score 0):

If server is Linux, you can link (actually soft link is OK, too).
ln AbcXyzPage1.html index.html
Now you have created index.html - the standard default. Any changes to AbcXyzPage1 will always be "seen" in index.html (since they are the same file).